# Espresso: can not click on pause button when UI is busy updating progress bar for download

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I'm testing an application using Espresso. The scenario is when the user click on the "Download" button, the data (a music/files/images etc.) starts being downloaded from the internet and UI shows a progress bar.  User should be able to click on the same button to pause the download. The test code was pretty simple:

```
// click to start download  
1) onView(withId(R.id.actionBtn)).perform(click());
// now either monitor the progress bar or simply click the same btn again to pause the download
2) onView(withId(R.id.actionBtn)).perform(click());
```

However with Espresso,  it seems that the 2) click() is not taken effect until the download is complete. i.e. not possible to "Pause" the download in the middle.

I understand that "By default, Espresso waits for UI operations in the current message queue to process and default AsyncTasks(synchronizes with the default AsyncTask thread pool) to complete before it moves on to the next test operation. ". I assume in this case, the UI is busy downloading and updating progress bar and only until download completes will the UI thread be idle to let the second Espresso operation to be executed ?

However, if I do need to test the "pause", and say, also monitor the progress bar to pause at, say, 20% of download,  is there a way to get around it using Espresso ?

I did read something about idling resources but not sure if it could or how to apply here. Any advice is appreciated.